# Regex subtract amount if the number is bigger than

Tags: regex, subtraction

I'm looking for a way to subtract a fixed amount if the number is bigger than specified value - using regex

e.g.

If the number is bigger than 10000 I want to subtract 5000, so it should look like:

175 -> 175
7831 -> 7831
12091 -> 7091

Comment: What language? Also regex isn't the way to do math.

Comment: Probably better to use some form of coded non-regex logic. Regex is not for everything...

Comment: You can't do math operations with regular expressions. Your solution is way easier than regexes anyway `if (value > 10000) value =- 5000;`

Comment: I think C#, I use Visual Web Ripper software and I'm trying to create a content transformation script.

Comment: @m0skit0, you can do some, but it's not very nice. ;-)

Comment: @Qtax can you show me an example of math operation with regex?

Comment: @m0skit0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245087/math-operations-in-regex example there, but works only in perl (perl evaluates the expression, not regex itself).

Comment: @m0skit0, example: Add 1 to all integers `2 > x >= 0`: `s/\b1\b/2/g; s/\b0\b/1/g;`.
In a [unary numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system) you can add one just by using `s/^/1/`.
In binary you could use an expression like `s/(?:0|\b(?=1)|(\G1))(?=1*$)/$1?0:1/ge`. I had to use `/e` here, but there could be a workaround using multiple expressions.
(Perl syntax.)

Comment: @Qtax: cool examples :) Although they don't work for decimal system, which is the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is used for **pattern** matching, replacing text.

You cannot use regex to do mathematical operations.

At max, in C# you can do this:

```
String s = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b\d{5,}\b", m => (int.Parse(m.Value)-5000).ToString());
```

So,

```
44 10000 15000 1 100
```

would become

```
44 5000 10000 1 100
```