# Notepad ++ Python code to add a value to numbers matching a pattern

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I have a notepad++ file with contents like below

```
{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:42:"Web Designing training institutes in Kochi";}i:357;a:1:
{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:32:"CSS training institutes in Kochi";}i:358;a:1:
{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:34:"HTML5 training institutes in Kochi";}i:359;a:1:
{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:39:"JavaScript training institutes in Kochi";}i:360;a:1:
{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:32:"XML training institutes in Kochi";}}}
```

I need a way to search for the phrase **";s:42:"** and increment the number part of the phrase   by 1. In this case, 42 will become 43.

I just need to do it. Dont care if it is through a python script like this

[Notepad++ Regular Expression add up numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506990/notepad-regular-expression-add-up-numbers)

or any other method.

Please help me. I am new to python/ any such language.

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner version:

```
perl -ne 's/(?<=;s:)(\d+)(?=:)/$1+1/ge; print' data.txt
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to run this

Comment: I executed it in online perl and this is the error Bareword found where operator expected at main.pl line 1, near "'s/(?<=;s:)(\d+)(?=:)/$1+1/ge; print' input"
 (Missing operator before input?)
syntax error at main.pl line 1, near "-ne"
Execution of main.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Where does that `input` come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
target_file = "some_file.txt"
with open("tmp_out.txt","w") as f_out:
   with open(target_file) as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            f_out.write(re.sub(";s:(\d+):",lambda match:";s:%d:"%(int(match.groups(0)[0])+1,line) + "\n")
shutil.move("tmp_out.txt",target_file)
```

something like that I think

or even better

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(target_file, inplace=True):
    print re.sub(";s:(\d+):",lambda match:";s:%d:"%(int(match.groups(0)[0])+1,line)
```

Comment: you can do `with open('path/to/out','w') as f_out and open('path/to/in') as f_in:` as one context manager

Comment: Is that true? Well I'll be damned :) I don't do any coding in Python2

Comment: It isn't me, but I don't see you incrementing the digit. Am I blind?

Answer (score 0):

Using your link as an example, the regex match should be:

```
def calculate(linenumber, match):
    editor.pyreplace(match.group(0), ';s:%d="%d"' % (match.group(1), str(int(match.group(2))+1)), 0, 0, linenumber, linenumber)

editor.pysearch(r';s:([0-9])="([0-9]+)"', calculate)
```

I think. I've never actually done this before!

Answer (score 0):

Though, one liner in Python is difficult to achieve, but you can use something similar using the callback feature of re.sub

```
repl = lambda e: e.group(1) + str(int(e.group(2))+1)
with open("in.txt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt","w") as fout:
        fout.write(re.sub(r"(;s:)(\d+):",repl, fin.read()))
```

Comment: Semicolon seems to be missing at main.pl line 1.
Bareword found where operator expected at main.pl line 2, near ") as"
 (Missing operator before as?)
Bareword found where operator expected at main.pl line 3, near ") as"
 (Missing operator before as?)
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at main.pl line 1, near "lambda e:"
syntax error at main.pl line 1, near "lambda e:"
Illegal declaration of anonymous subroutine at mai

Comment: @user3290168: This is Python not Perl