# Notepad++ : Add the chapter number on each line with REG-EXP

Tags: regex, notepad++

Given the following file :

```
Chapter 1
1 line 1
2 line 2
3 line 3

Chapter 2
1 line 4
2 line 5
```

I would like to add the chapter number on each line number :

```
Chapter 1
1-1 line1
1-2 line 2
…
Chapter 2
2-1 line 4
…
```

Is it possible using regular expressions ?
Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ Regular Expression add up numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506990/notepad-regular-expression-add-up-numbers)

Comment: It can be done with a regex in Find Replace dialog, just you would need to click Replace all until no match is found. I have already answered a similar question, but cannot look fIr it now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It can't be done in 1 shot can it?

Comment: @MYGz I can't say for sure but it probably can be done with one regex but multiple replace all hits. I am on a mobile now so I cannot check.

Comment: Try `^Chapter\h+(\d+).*\R(\1-\d.*\R)*+\K(?!\1-\d)\d+` regex and `$1-$&` replacement. Click *Replace all* until no match is found (until 0 occuurences are replaced).

Answer (score 0):

Use

*Find What*: `^Chapter\h+(\d+).*\R(\1-\d.*\R)*+\K(?!\1-\d)\d+`
*Replace With*: `$1-$&`

Hit *Replace All* until no replacement takes place.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `Chapter` - a literla char sequence
- `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1 matching one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\R` - a line break char (sequence)
- `(\1-\d.*\R)*+` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\1` - same value as captured into Group 1
  - `-\d` - a hyphen and a digit
  - `.*\R` - the rest of the line with a line break char (sequence)
- `\K`  - a match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far in the current iteration
- `(?!\1-\d)\d+` - one or more digits, but not the same number as captured into group 1 and followed with `-` and a digit

[image]