# Evaluate an expression while replacing in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
Input:
3
9
16
```

I need an output file which adds a constant `10` to every element in input-

```
Output:
13
19
26
```

Is there a quick way to evaluate expressions in Notepad++?
I tried a couple of things, including:

```
Search: [0-9]+
Replace: $0+10
```

But the output I get is:

```
3+10
9+10
16+10
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see if there is a way to edit a backreference without the use of some scripting plugin. Though I doubt it =). Here are some related questions I found that might provide some insight: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20506990/9758194) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/968315/1059206)

Comment: **Duplicate of [Notepad++ Find/Replace number with Increment Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `calculate.py`):

```
import re
def calculate(match):
    return '%s' % (str(int(match.group(1)) + 10))

editor.rereplace('(\d+)', calculate)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> calculate)
- Done

Comment: Thanks, it works. I had no idea, I could integrate Python in this.

Comment: @Tushar: You're welcome, glad it helps.These python scripts are very usefull to bypass the Notepad++ limitations.

Comment: @Tushar: Don't worry, I'm sure you didn't.