# Doing math on Apache RedirectMatch for WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245087/math-operations-in-regex), but I am not using the Perl module.

### Problem

I am using WordPress 4.3 and I need to add a number like `1122000` to `post_id` for permalinks structure.

This is what I have as default URL structure:

```
mysite.com/?post_type=orders&p=139
```

and this is desired permalink structure:

```
mysite.com/orders/1122139
```

Please note that we can't just concatenate `1122` into the `post_id` as `post_id` may exceed `999` at future.

### My efforts

In my first try I used `add_rewrite_rule` function:

```
function my_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^orders/1122([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=orders&p=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_basic');
```

Which works only if id is lower than `1000`.

In my second try I directly used Apache RedirectMatch like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/orders/(\d+) /?post_type=orders&p=($1-1122000)
```

in `.htaccess` file with no success.

Is there another way to implement a 7 digit serial number based on post_id?

Comment: Simple answer is that you can't do math with a regex. You'd need to use some code on a backend page to capture the request and do any mathematical processing on it

Answer (score 0):

Regex does not allow you to do math. `RewriteRule` doesn't allow you do math either.

You should look into modifying the data in the database. You could add that number to the post id in the database, while taking care that no foreign key constrainst are broken (That means, either you configure explicit foreign keys with `on update cascade` option, or you update manually every field that contains a reference to the post id.

Another option would be to write a routing plugin for wordpress, which would allow you to enforce any rewrite rules you liked.