# How can I extract a certain number from a string using Regular expressions?

Tags: regex, epub, adobe-indesign, calibre

I think this is probably easy but I don't have the time to learn how to do it.

In a html file, I have a certain class of paragraph, let´s say:

```
<p class="footnote"></p>
```

The "p" tag is always followed by numbers, which increase by one in every instance. Let's say the first number is "43". I want the series of numbers to start from 1, so I need to substract 42 from all paragraphs.

For example, I would want to go from:

```
<p class="footnote">43. Lorem</p>
<p class="footnote">44. Ipsum</p>. 
<p class="footnote">45. Dolor</p>.
```

to

```
<p class="footnote">1. Lorem</p>
<p class="footnote">2. Ipsum</p>. 
<p class="footnote">3. Dolor</p>.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Sources say regex can't do math. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245087/math-operations-in-regex 
If you're working with InDesign you'll need to use a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a regex that'll handle `<p class="footnote">43. Lorem</p>` the answer is [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2482744).

Assuming you've extracted the string `43. Lorem` from a tag and you want to get a number out then it depends on your requirements:

To find any number: `\d+`

To find any number at the beginning: `^\d+`

To find any number followed by a period: `\d+\.`

A more complete solution will require more details about the problem including the programming language you want to use.

Comment: Ok I think I'll have to find an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get the text using javascript (though I'll be using jQuery), split the text, get the first element, and convert to an integer.

```
$(".footnote").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();  // Get text
    var num = text.split(/\s+/g)[0]; // Split by whitespace and get the first elem
    console.log(parseInt(num)); // Convert the elem to an int
});
```