# Arithmetic with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, string, math

What regular expression can I use that **sums** or **subtracts** a part of a string?
For instance:`I can count to 10!` and it replaces as `I can count to 9!`

Comment: Regex is not a programming language. You cannot do `1 + 1=2`.

Comment: @noob You can do simple arithmetic: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245087/math-operations-in-regex

Comment: Yes and that uses expressions in perl. I was talking about plain regex.

Comment: @jiaweizhang perl has some advanced regex functions beyond what javascript has.  If you want to do it in javascript, you need write a function to modify the regex match.

Comment: My b. Didn't see the js part

Comment: You need a callback. Match \d+, in callback subtract 1, then return the itoa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex function to change the matched value.  Something like this should work:

```
var str = "I can count to 10!";

str = str.replace(/[0-9]+[0-9]/, function (match, capture) { return match-1;});
console.log(str)
```

You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/rmtuk3j1/

Comment: `/\d+/` is a simpler regex.

Comment: This regexp won't work if the original string has a 1-digit number.

Comment: It won't work for any number, but the function after the regex helped me!